# iPhone6 Plus with iOS 8.3 easily got killed by system when virtual memory is over 1.5GB

Tags: ios, memory

Our app is a map-based navigation app. and we are facing the problem recently. After upgrade to iOS 8.3, iPhone6 plus the app always crashes when the virtual memory grew over 1.5GB.
When it crashes, activity monitor shows Real Mem can be over 100MB to over 300MB, and Virtual Mem is awalys over 1.5GB. Also from the system crash log, our app used about 166000~168500 rpages.  I think we are probably reaching the limit of VM. Do you have any debug tips to help us find the large virtual memory usage? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should not load all the data in the memory.

You should 'page' them, by loading 100 by 100 or something like that and when loading new 100 results, unload the 100 precedents.